# One of EV3 motors doesn't respond in demo program

Tags: ev3, programming

I just bought the EV3 set and made the "TRACK3R" model. When I run the demo program from LEGO the port B motor does not work - only the port C motor is works. But if I try "Motor Control" both ports are working properly. I have already tried replacing the cable but it had no impact. So how can I fix this?

Comment: When you say it "does not work" what is it doing or not doing that is different? Also try swapping the motors to see if the problem is the motor or the port itself.